# Using React, how can I attach a click event to a class or ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I've got an SVG with hundreds of `<circle>` elements that I would like to attach a click event to. Using jQuery, that's really easy:

```
$('circle').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

How can I do this in React?

Normally I would attach an event listener to the element directly:

`<circle onClick={(e) => handleClick()} />`

Seeing as there are hundreds of elements, this would be very tedious. Is there a way I can attach a single event listener to *all* circle elements?

My working solution uses vanilla JS, but it involves interacting with the DOM directly:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const circles = document.querySelectorAll('circle');
    for (const trigger of circles) {
      trigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert('clicked');
    });
  }
}, []);
```

I don't get any errors and this *does* work, but it doesn't feel like React. Am I missing something? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Just brainstormin, but since click events bubble down the hierarchy unless explicitly told not to, adding an event click handler to the parent and "guess" which type of element is clicked might work...

Comment: Are you using `React` to render all the `circles`. ? React is not a dom manipulation library and is not expected to solve these issues, unless `react` itself renders the elements.

Comment: In react you use [onClick](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: How are you rendering those circles? Your approach actually breaks component abstraction. It is anti pattern to directly manipulate the DOM. A good solution would be to extract `Circle` to be a standalone component. Everything depends on how the `svg` is generated

Comment: If React renders those circles you should extract a component `Circle` that renders a `circle` and attaches your handler. Then instead of rendering `circle` directly render `Circle` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should worry for with vanilla JS DOM manipulation in such cases, but if you want to make it react-ish you can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

First define your context:

```
const CircleContext = React.createContext();
```

then wrap your app (or part of app where circles will be used) with `CircleContext.Provider` and set it's value to desired callback:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <CircleContext.Provider
      value={e => {
        console.log("Circle clicked!");
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <Circle />
      </div>
    </CircleContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And consume that context in your circle component (I used `useContext` hook):

```
function Circle() {
  const context = useContext(CircleContext);
  return <button onClick={context}>My Button</button>;
}
```

With this implementation every `Circle` component will use same `onClick` handler defined in `CircleContext.Provider`.

Example [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-meadow-jorqn).

Comment: My `<circle>` elements live inside a much larger SVG that has paths, polygons and rectangles in it and are being instantiated as part of the SVG as a whole. It sounds like I'd still need to edit each instance of `<circle>` with this approach, which is what I'm trying to avoid (there are hundreds of them).

Comment: @MichaelLynch In that case, you could only replace `document.querySelectorAll('circle')` with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).querySelectorAll('circle')` inside `componentDidMount`.